# Fade in and fade out transition using onClick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions

I'm trying to appear a background color with transition when a click event happens and without further interaction fade out the background color after 1 or 2 seconds.

Basically i want to do what `active` property does in css but for a click event.

My current approach needs to fire the click event for the second time to fadeout the background color. How can i do this in one click

My approach

```
    handleClick(id) {
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        })
    }

    <div className={this.state.active ? "txt_vote_bar_div txt_vote_bar_div_active" : "txt_vote_bar_div txt_vote_bar_div_notactive"} 
        onClick={this.handleClick()}>
    </div>
```

My CSS

```
.txt_vote_bar_div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #C6C6C6;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.txt_vote_bar_div_active {
    background-color: #001f3f;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

.txt_vote_bar_div_notactive {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: you are calling the handler instead of passing a ref. this `onClick={this.handleClick()}` should be changed to this `onClick={this.handleClick}`

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Please find my answer and let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please find running example](http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/6jum5yya/2/)

> In your code one mistake, you did i.e **onClick={this.handleClick()}**
>   so due to this after every renders your click event is triggered.

This is What I did.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    state = {
        active: false
    }
    handleClick(e) {
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                active: !this.state.active
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
    render() {
        return ( 
          <div className = { this.state.active ? "txt_vote_bar_div txt_vote_bar_div_active" : "txt_vote_bar_div txt_vote_bar_div_notactive" } onClick = { this.handleClick.bind(this) }></div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
    Hello initialName = "World" / > ,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by setting a timeout to change it back.

```
handleClick(id) {

        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });

        // The timeout will trigger after 1000ms. Use a fat arrow function
        // to keep the same reference to this.
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                 active: false
            });
        }, 1000);
}
```

If you can't use fat arrow function you could assign `this` to a variable like `self` and call `self.setState` from within the timeout handler.